# Wildcards in windows directories using cat

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard

In linux, if I have:

folder1/
 -- file.txt
folder2/
 -- file.txt

I can do
    $$ cat folder*/file.txt

How can I do the same, in one command, in windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b/s/a-d ^| findstr /r "folder*\\file*"') do type %%f
```

This is the closest thing that I can think out at the moment.If you intend to use this in command line you should use `%f` .`Type` command supports wildcards and can print more than one file ,but does not search for files in sub directories.